# Insufficient Memory error being thrown

Tags: c#

```
namespace Calendar
{
    public partial class MainCalendar : Form
    {
        private JArray items;
        private List<String> AMList = new List<String>();
        private List<String> PMList = new List<String>();
        private List<String> accessToCalendarFilepath = new List<String>();
        private List<CalendarModel> people;
        private List<List<CalendarModel>> managers = new List<List<CalendarModel>>();
        private List<String> userSelection = new List<String>();
        private bool authorizedAccess = false;
        private String javaScriptFileContainingJSONObject = "";

        public MainCalendar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           

            var locationInformation = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "location.json";

            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(locationInformation))
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
            {
                JArray o = (JArray)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                items = o;
            }

            foreach (var item in items.Children())
            {
                var itemProperties = item.Children<JProperty>();
                // you could do a foreach or a linq here depending on what you need to do exactly with the value
                var myElement = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "name");
                var myElementValue = myElement.Value; ////This is a JValue type

                if(myElementValue.ToString().Contains("AM"))
                {
                    AMList.Add(myElementValue.ToString());
                }

                if (myElementValue.ToString().Contains("PM"))
                {
                    PMList.Add(myElementValue.ToString());
                }
            }

            mondayAM.DataSource = AMList.ToArray();
            tuesdayAM.DataSource = AMList.ToArray();
            wednesdayAM.DataSource = AMList.ToArray();
            thursdayAM.DataSource = AMList.ToArray();
            fridayAM.DataSource = AMList.ToArray();

            mondayPM.DataSource = PMList.ToArray();
            tuesdayPM.DataSource = PMList.ToArray();
            wednesdayPM.DataSource = PMList.ToArray();
            thursdayPM.DataSource = PMList.ToArray();
            fridayPM.DataSource = PMList.ToArray();
            loadAccessControl("accesscontrol.json");
            dateTimePicker1.AlwaysChooseMonday(dateTimePicker1.Value);
            String dateSelected = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
            findManagerForSelectedDate(dateSelected);
        }

        public void loadAccessControl(String fileName)
        {
            var accessControlInformation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fileName;
            List<AccessControl> accounts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccessControl>>(File.ReadAllText(accessControlInformation));

            foreach (AccessControl account in accounts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(account.accountName);

                if (account.accountName.ToLower().Contains(Environment.UserName.ToLower()))
                {
                    foreach (CalendarFile file in account.files)
                    {
                        // Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "content" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + file.Filename);
                        accessToCalendarFilepath.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "content" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + file.Filename);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
            contentsOfFile();            
        }

        private void contentsOfFile()
        {
            String line;

            foreach(var file in accessToCalendarFilepath)
            {
                StreamReader contentsOfJSONFile = new StreamReader(file);

                while((line = contentsOfJSONFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if(line.Contains("var "))
                    {
                        javaScriptFileContainingJSONObject = javaScriptFileContainingJSONObject + "[";
                    }
                    else if(line.Contains("];"))
                    {
                        javaScriptFileContainingJSONObject = javaScriptFileContainingJSONObject + "]";
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        javaScriptFileContainingJSONObject = javaScriptFileContainingJSONObject + line;
                    }
                }

                people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CalendarModel>>((string)javaScriptFileContainingJSONObject);                
                managers.Add(people);
                javaScriptFileContainingJSONObject = "";
            }
        }

        private void findManagerForSelectedDate(String dateSelected)
        {
            dateSelected = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();

            List<String> managerNames = new List<String>();

            foreach(var item in managers)
            {
                foreach (var subitem in item)
                {
                    CalendarModel c = subitem;
                    Console.WriteLine(c.date);
                    c.name = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(c.name);

                    if (userSelection.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var addedUser in userSelection.ToArray())
                        {
                            if (!addedUser.Contains(c.name))
                            {
                                userSelection.Add(c.name); // CRASHING HERE
 //{"Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."}
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        userSelection.Add(c.name);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

I keep running out of memory.

The `CalendarModel` class:

```
namespace Calendar
{
    class CalendarModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public string date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mondayAM")]
        public string mondayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mondayPM")]
        public string mondayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tuesdayAM")]
        public string tuesdayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tuesdayPM")]
        public string tuesdayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("wednesdayAM")]
        public string wednesdayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("wednesdayPM")]
        public string wednesdayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thursdayAM")]
        public string thursdayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thursdayPM")]
        public string thursdayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fridayAM")]
        public string fridayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fridayPM")]
        public string fridayPM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("saturdayAM")]
        public string saturdayAM { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("saturdayPM")]
        public string saturdayPM { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I keep crashing at

```
userSelection.Add(c.name)
```

Comment: This is not a complete example. Missing a lot of information about your classes. Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you share what is is `managers`, `item`, and `userSelection`?

Comment: Your function has the dateSelected parameter which it is overwriting immediately. Also what managers refers to is unclear, also checking if a list has items is unneeded when using a foreach loop.

Comment: i know the date is overwritten (its there for testing so I don't need to keep clicking the dateTimePicker)

Comment: You are changing userSelcetion collection in foreach. Becareful there

Comment: What is "managers" defined as?  managerNames  is unused...I'm guessing we are missing a bunch of code that is key.  Plus I see issues with your converting toarray (userSelection.ToArray()) for no apparent reason, but without know what it is... also the most important part.. WHAT LINE are you getting the error on??

Comment: private List<List<CalendarModel>> managers = new List<List<CalendarModel>>();

Comment: The answer here is obvious - you haven't posted all the code, there are a lot of managers, items and selections and you probably have a runaway loop too

Comment: OK. I can post my entire code. Give me a moment

Comment: @softwareisfun don't post the entire code. *Clean it up* and post *only* what is necessary *for others* to reproduce the problem

Comment: Indeed, what M.kazem Akhgary is saying: you are changing userSelection within the loop where you evaluate over it. That probably invalidates the array. Maybe comment on what you are trying to do there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a close look at what you are doing

```
foreach (var addedUser in userSelection.ToArray())
{
    if (!addedUser.Contains(c.name))
    {
        userSelection.Add(c.name);
    }
}
```

You are adding to **userSelection** in the userSelection loop
The test is on `!addedUser.Contains`

You should not even be able to do that but I think the ToArrray() is letting it happen

So you add Sally
Then then Mark
Then you add Mark again because in the loop Mark != Sally

You are not using `List<String> managerNames = new List<String>();`

```
private void findManagerForSelectedDate(String dateSelected)
{
    dateSelected = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

You pass in dateSelected, then overright with dateTimePicker1, and then you don't even use it

Most of you code makes very little sense to me